# How to select from two tables and compare the sum from first table if its greater than that in second table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one is fees and another one is tblinvoice .tblinvoice has a primary key invoiceid which is a foreign key in fees table . So I want to sum all amountpaid from fees table for each invoiceid then I compare that sum to the amount of the coresponding invoiceid in tblinvoice  it should be greater or equals  . I tried to google and also tried to create the query by my own but no luck . Here is what I tried .

```
select  fees.invoiceid,  SUM(fees.amountpaid) AS finalpay from fees
INNER JOIN tblinvoice
ON fees.invoiceid = tblinvoice.invoiceid

WHERE fees.amountpaid >= (select tblinvoice.amount)

GROUP BY invoiceid 
ORDER BY invoiceid
```

Comment: you should also post datatables plus example data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get `finalpay` for each `invoiceid` in `fees` and the join to `tblinvoice`:

```
select
  t.invoiceid, t.amount, f.finalpay
from tblinvoice t inner join (
  select invoiceid,  sum(amountpaid) as finalpay 
  from fees
  group by invoiceid
) f on f.invoiceid = t.invoiceid
where f.finalpay >= t.amount
order by t.invoiceid
```

Comment: If we are looking for stars you are one (This worked perfectly with no extra changes )

Answer (score 1):

Your condition should be in the HAVING clause, where you can use aggregate expressions like `SUM(fees.amountpaid)` or its alias `finalpay`.

```
SELECT tblinvoice.invoiceid, SUM(fees.amountpaid) AS finalpay
FROM tblinvoice
INNER JOIN fees ON fees.invoiceid = tblinvoice.invoiceid
GROUP BY tblinvoice.invoiceid, tblinvoice.amount
HAVING finalpay >= tblinvoice.amount
ORDER BY tblinvoice.invoiceid
```

Depending on your server version and settings, you can remove `tblinvoice.amount` from the GROUP BY clause, since it's functionally dependent on `tblinvoice.invoiceid`.

Comment: Your effort is appreciated